# How do I match my ScrollView to my background?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

Basically, I have a menu containing a scrollview which can be opened as a popupwindow. However, the issue is that in the previews for the graphical layout, the ScrollView seems to have different dimensions on all devices.

Having a similar problem for other issues, when I ran the emulator for a large device, I found that the dimensions actually worked fine. So I was wondering if one of these two things are possible:

a) Is there a way to make the ScrollView line up to points on the background (i.e., a visible area in the background showing where it should be),

b) Given that the graphical previews are not always accurate, which device should I use in the graphical preview as a reference for how my layout will actually look?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you setting your dimensions for your ScrollView? Do you mean that it doesn't scale on devices appropriately (sometimes the ScrollView is too big or too small depending on the device)?

Comment: Yeah, effectively. Same with the top & bottom margins.
The left and right margins are quite consistent, given screen width doesn't change much.
But then again, the graphical preview says that Nexus 10 will have a super-small, high up scroll view, when in reality it's virtually normal sized, and near-correctly positioned, so I don't know if the graphical preview just sucks ass.